# How to get a tensor's value in TensorFlow (without making another session)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensor

I'm finding a way to getting a tensor's value. In most case, the problem would be solved by calling "sess.run(target_op)". However, I want to know another way. I am editing the code downloaded from GitHub so there's already a session running code there. Without touching the session running part, is there any way to get some specific tensor value? In my case, the code is built for getting accuracy for image recognition. While session runs and doing the accuracy evaluation I also want to get "prediction" tensor value in the same session without creating another session. For example, an operation like tf.Print shows tensor value througha terminal window without running session directly(in the first figure we just have to do sess.run(e) to print out tensor from c)
[example of tf.Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyj2D.png)

```
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(3)
c = tf.add(a,b)

#print tensor c (which is 8)
d = tf.Print(c,[c])
f = tf.constant(2)
e = tf.multiply(f,d)
sess = tf.Session()

#print operation can be executed without running the session directly
g = sess.run(e)`
```

Like the tf.Print is there any operation that gets tensor value without running session directly? (like the second figure)
[example of operation I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atjtt.png)

More specifically, what I want is to get the value of tensor(with actual numbers and arrays, not just 'tensor' data structure)and pass it to the global variable to access the value freely even after the session closes. The session only executes the operator which is located at end of the graph while the tensor I want the value is located in the middle of the graph. With restriction that I cannot create more session than the original code has, is there any way to get the specific tensor value?( I can't use .eval() or .run() because either needs to access 'session'. the code I am editing runs the code by using slim.evaluate_once function and as session() is binded to the function, I cannot approach to session())

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you can't just call any tensor from the graph, provided you feed in the appropriate `feed_dict`. For instance say you want a tensor called `biasAdd:0` and your so called-end tensor is called `prediction`

Then you can just get this tensor and evaluate it:

```
tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("biasAdd:0")
tensor_value, prediction_value = ses.run([tensor, prediction],... )
```

In tensorflow you have to use run or eval to get a numerical value from the graph

Comment: Thank you for answering my quesetion! I have just added more description about the problem. Could you look at it?

Comment: What about now?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/r1.5/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py - This is the code I am looking at. The tensor I am looking for is "logits"(line139) and the session runs in slim.evaluation.evaluate_once function (line181~187). In the case I have to let the function untouched(because the function provides restoring checkpoint_path function and evaluating accuracy at the same time), is there a way to get value of "logits"? I think if I use the way you just advised, I have to fix the tensorflow api.

Comment: Or should I not use the evaluate_once function and use another function because there's no other way?

Comment: The value of logits changes with every batch, so I would probably suggest adding a hook that gets the value of the logits each time the eval function runs. To do this, add this argument to the `slim.evaluation.evaluate_once` function call: `hooks=[
tf.train.LoggingTensorHook([logits], every_n_iter=1])`